# nosetests on underscore-prefixed modules

Tags: python, nosetests

I have a directory structure

```
+ (project-root)
+- setup.py
+- setup.cfg
+-+ src/
  +- asdf.py
  +- asdf_test.py
```

and a directory structure

```
+ (project-root)
+- setup.py
+- setup.cfg
+-+ src/
  +- _asdf.py
  +- _asdf_test.py
```

In setup.py, I have:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name='project',
    description='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    setup_requires=['nose>=1.0'],
    test_suite='nose.collector'
)
```

The `setup.cfg` is empty in the above scenarios (devoid of any `[nosetests]` section).

The first directory structure's tests are run with `python setup.py nosetests`. The second directory structure's tests aren't. How do I make the second directory structure's tests run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `--ignore-files` is set up to ignore all `_` prefixed files (see [here](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/f349692bd42edb04252d740c1d401079142eb24b/unit_tests/test_selector.py#L20)). Setting it to `--ignore-files='^$'` makes everything happy and dandy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `--match` flag or a custom selector?  Both of these methods are detailed in [this post](http://www.metaklass.org/nose-creating-your-own-runner/).

Comment: No dice. Still ignores the private module. (EDIT: for regex matches - haven't tried the custom selector yet; will try next)

(EDIT EDIT: although I'd really prefer an option I can just dump into setup.cfg)